# Macbook pro (Retina 15 inch Late 2013) Horizontal gray line across screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I have bought this computer New at the Apple Store in 2014.

Since yesterday it's showing horizontal gray lines across the screen. I suspect a hardware defect because that's how my 2 others macs older started showing problems too.

All updates are installed and restarted the computer a few times.

Anyone would know if this is really an hardware issue? If it is probably looks at very expensive repair.

[image]

Comment: The lines don't show on the picture; suspect hardware.

Comment: Yes I am afraid it is indeed. Thanks for the input. Just closed the computer and opened again, it flickered and didn't look great for a couple of secs (pretty messy) and then like by magic it's looking good again. It's going to come back, I am sure. I ought to backup everything. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a hardware defect, because, as Tetsujin mentioned, the lines do not show up on the picture. I would suggest going to an Apple retail store or otherwise the store you bought the Macbook to get it checked up. Are you still under warranty/AppleCare?